# Face recognition library in python gives out failed to initiate process when running a command. How do i solve this?

Tags: python, face-recognition

This is the command i ran in cmd.

import face-recognition

face_recognition ‘./known/me.jpg’ ‘./unknown/testPhoto.jpg’

Comment: "Ran in cmd"? Not in Python? What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: I ran in cmd ofcourse. Also, I have a python file which does not distinguish the faces. It processed both faces as the same face. I got “failed to create process”

Comment: The message i got was “Failed to create process”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the installation mistake i made. I didn’t create its own virtual environment. I don’t know actually why it didn’t work with that virtual environment till i created its’ own and installed it again.